# Call the axis after pressing a menu button in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to teach myself D3 with examples from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock.

I took the scatterchart and I'm trying to load various data depending on what menu-item is active.

Everything is working fine, but I got one problem I just can't solve.
The xAxis should update itself depending on the values from the data linked to the menu item.

I was searching the web for an answer, but couldn't find one that worked for me.

I think the problem (and solution) lies in this part of the code;

```
function updateChart() {
    svg.selectAll('.dot')
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('cx', function(d) {
            return x(d.data[parameter]);

        })

    svg.select(".x.axis")
       .call(xAxis);

}
```

I made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5m2ep1zq/) to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's going on.

- You successfully generated your `xAxis` with the correct `x` scale in the first go around, however
- You didn't update your `xAxis` with the new domain of data

You were right in that you had to re-update your scales whenever you click on your labels.

I've done a couple of things:

- Add a `sourceData` variable after you've coerced your numbers, for all your functions to reference
- Add a `updateXScale(data)` function that will simply update your `x` scale's `domain`
- Have it called every time you click a label. Not only will this fix your x scale, it will also enable the correct scaling of your x-coordinates for your `.dot`'s.

Here's what it looks like all together. I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxarturo/5m2ep1zq/2/) that has a working version of your example.

And here's your `updateChart` function for reference:

```
function updateChart() {
  updateXScale(sourceData);

  svg.selectAll('.dot')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return x(d.data[parameter]);
    });
  svg.select(".x.axis")
    .call(xAxis);

}
```